# Round an int to the nearest in 5X Table?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

In my iPhone app I need to round an integer to the nearest multiple of 5.

E.g. Round 6 to = 10 and round 23 to = 25 etc

### Edit

I forgot to say, I only want to round up! In all situations, so 22 would round up to 25 for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to always round up, you can use the following:

```
int a = 22;
int b = (a + 4) / 5 * 5; // b = 25;
```

If `a` can be a float, you should add a cast to `int` as follows:

```
int b = ((int)a + 4) / 5 * 5; // b = 25;
```

Note that you can use the function `ceil` to accomplish the same result:

```
int a = 22;
int b = ceil((float)a / 5) * 5; // b = 25;
```

---

**Old Answer:**

To round to the nearest multiple of `5`, you can do the following:

```
int a = 23;
int b = (int)(a + 2.5) / 5 * 5;
```

Comment: What does putting (int) in front of the sum do?

Comment: Doh, forgot to mention a key bit of info. I always want to round, edited my question slightly. (Thanks for answering!)

Answer (score 4):

**Use :**

```
int rounded = (i%5==0) ? i : i+5-(i%5);
```

---

**Example :**

```
    for (int i=1; i<25; i++)
    {
        int k= (i%5==0) ? i : i+5-(i%5);

        printf("i  : %d => rounded : %d\n",i,k);
    }
```

**Output :**

```
i  : 1 => rounded : 5
i  : 2 => rounded : 5
i  : 3 => rounded : 5
i  : 4 => rounded : 5
i  : 5 => rounded : 5
i  : 6 => rounded : 10
i  : 7 => rounded : 10
i  : 8 => rounded : 10
i  : 9 => rounded : 10
i  : 10 => rounded : 10
i  : 11 => rounded : 15
i  : 12 => rounded : 15
i  : 13 => rounded : 15
i  : 14 => rounded : 15
i  : 15 => rounded : 15
i  : 16 => rounded : 20
i  : 17 => rounded : 20
i  : 18 => rounded : 20
i  : 19 => rounded : 20
i  : 20 => rounded : 20
i  : 21 => rounded : 25
i  : 22 => rounded : 25
i  : 23 => rounded : 25
i  : 24 => rounded : 25
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3

```
extension Int {
    func nearestFive() -> Int {
        return (self + 4) / 5 * 5
    }
}
```

use

```
let a = 23.nearestFive()
print(a) // 25
```

Answer (score 1):

For an integer solution use mod 5 biased by 4 for the rounding:

```
int i;
int i5;

i = 6;
i5 = i + 4 - ((i+4) % 5);
NSLog(@"i: %i, i5: %i", i, i5);

i = 22;
i5 = i + 4 - ((i+4) % 5);
NSLog(@"i: %i, i5: %i", i, i5);
NSLog output:
```

> i: 6, i5: 10
>   i: 22, i5: 25

Answer (score 1):

For rounding up to the next multiple of 5, e.g., the following can be used:

```
(int) (5.0 * ceil((number/5.0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need another answer to this question, but I personally think this is neater:

```
int ans = ceil(input / 5.0) * 5.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need integers to be round off, `num+5-(num%5)` should be sufficient.

**Old Answer**

I do not know much about objective-c but shouldn't this be sufficient.

```
r = num%5
r > 2 ? num+5-r : n-r
```

Comment: Sorry I made a silly mistake in my question, thanks for your answer, I've altered my question.

Comment: what about 6 then ? should it round up to 10 or 5. You should edit your question again if 6 is supposed to round to 10. And if that is the case, the answer would simply become "num+5-(num%5)".